# How to display just few from original text using UITextView - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am creating a sample app to display some texts which contain many lines of content using `UITextView`. For example, my texts has 400 characters then it should display only 200 characters and end with `...` for identify to user that content has more text to display, then i just put some button which `title` "more detail", by click on that button then 400 characters should be shown.

How can i achieve something like that? Thank in advance.

Comment: lot of solutions ..https://www.google.co.in/search?ei=x_xzW4SCHIfovATCzILwDw&q=read+more+textview+swift&oq=red+more+textview+swift&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i13k1.50589.51178.0.54370.3.3.0.0.0.0.192.359.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.359...0i7i30k1.0.5uc6bjc0c8M

Answer (score 0):

One of the textView methods might be useful for your purpose. With the textView delegate method given below, you can limit textView characters to 200. Check the code below for limiting the text to 200 characters.

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    return newText.count <= 200
    }
```